# When did subscribers actually receive their Dragon Magazine issues?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

Would a subscriber receive issues the month before the posted month on the cover of each issue? None of the publishing info on the old *Dragon* magazine uploads/scans have anything about expected arrival of each issue. I know a lot of monthly magazines are about a month early with releases - was it the same with *Dragon* magazine?

Comment: The store owner we knew complained that he didn't subscribe any more because the subscription would be there the same day as his normal magazines for sale in the shop. But I'm not in an English speaking country, so maybe not even the target market back then. The fact that they *expected* their subscription to arrive sooner might be a hint at how it was in other markets. But consider this an anecdote, not data. That's why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Does “back in the day” reference any particular time period here? I note the question was originally tagged with AD&D 1e, but Dragon Magazine ran up to 2007 in print, lasting well into D&D 4e's time period. (I've replaced that tag with dungeons-and-dragons because [adnd-1e] doesn't appear to be describing or correlated to anything about the question.)

Comment: Voting to close since there are too many times and places to make a cohesive non-list answer.

Answer (score 9):

My subscriptions in the early to mid 80's and late 70's usually arrived around the first of the month of the subscription. (Lived in US, east coast)

When I moved to Texas it tended to arrive before the month by about a week.  It varied.

Had a break for a number of years. Then picked it up again and it tended to arrive about a week before the named month or as the month started. We are relying on 20+ year old memory here, so allow for an error tolerance and the fact that "I got it when I got it" was my approach (in terms of its importance).